# DNS Lookup takes too long

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, bind, ubuntu-12.04

I've got BIND9 DNS running on local Ubuntu machine. Used https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns-configuration.html to set it up.

Everything works ok, but sometimes it take awhile to load, especially the first visit.

[image: DNS Lookup]

Is there anyway I can troubleshoot to find the the cause for such slow lookup? Could it be configuration settings?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are all your problems related to your **miss-use** of the `.local` domain?  Are you sure your system isn't attempting [Multicast DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) resolution and timing out?

If this is the problem, you need to disable avahi/bonjour lookups on your systems.

Answer (score 0):

> Everything works ok, but sometimes it take awhile to load, especially the first visit.

If you set up a local name server then nothing is cached until you visit it.  A local name server will look everything up via the root name servers and then follow all the referrals to get the answer.  Hosting your own DNS is a good thing, but whatever you make the DNS server, you have to keep it running all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If using OS X Yosemite (10.10) or later the problem could be the URL being used. OS X uses mDNS protocol (with the bonjour service) in top-level domain names that end with a .local suffix as your screenshot shows ([Here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204684) you can read further about that topic).

A recommendatio is not to use the .local sufix anymore, if you find that difficult, then you can try to use a mdns proxy, [Here](https://blog.rebex.net/multicast-dns-apple-and-local-domains/#thesolution) you can find more information about that.